# Can't update Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I want to update the eclipse I get the following error:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>   Unable to connect to repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/content.xml Connection
>   timed out: connect Unable to connect to repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/content.xml Connection
>   timed out: connect

the available software sites are: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo and 
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7

The version of eclipse is 3.7.2

Comment: These should really be up, especially with the retention time specified as 'indefinitely' on the update site list (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites). Honestly, they really peev me off with the messing about with update sites they do.

Comment: You could just download the Eclipse package you need, unzip, and add your additional plug-ins.

Comment: I am doing this from behind a proxy, so that may be the problem. I just downloaded thes package so everthing is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now set the proxy with

```
Window -> Preferences then General -> Network Connection
```

There I filled in my proxy and now I can update eclipse without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

At work, I am behind a proxy, so on my MacBook Pro, I had to click on Eclipse->Preferences->General->Network Connections.

From there, choose Active Provider:  Manual, and ensure the proxy entries below are all checked.

If there are no proxy entries, you will have to manually enter them.

Comment: Even if I followed the steps provided by you I am getting the same error "Unable to connect to repository http://opensource.cpupk.com/decompiler/content.xml Connection timed out: connect"